# How to get whole text including tags from an XML file with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, text, tags

I have an xml file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<legends>
<legend>
<number>1</number>
<legendString><ul><li>1.across:a system of rules of conduct or method of practice</li><li>1.down:a disagreement or argument about something important</li><li>2.down:any broad thin surface</li><li>3.across:the passage of  pedestrians or vehicles </li></ul></legendString>
</legend>
......
<legends>
```

How can I take whole text including tags using jQuery.
The string

```
<ul><li>1.across:a system of rules of conduct or method of practice</li><li>1.down:a disagreement or argument about something important</li><li>2.down:any broad thin surface</li><li>3.across:the passage of  pedestrians or vehicles </li></ul>
```

should be passed if I make a function call.
If I call:

```
var legendStr = $(this).find("legendString").text();
```

tags will not be present in legendStr.

How can I proceed.

This is the jQuery Script:

```
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*233);
    $.get("legends.xml",{},function(xml){  



       $(xml).find("legend").each(function(){   


                if(randomnumber == $(this).find("number").text())
                {
              var c = "legendString";

              var legendStr = $(this).find(c).html();         


              $("#sidebar > ul").html(legendStr);
                }



       });
       },"xml");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You want 
    $(this).find("legendString").html()</strike>

I took a closer look at jQuery's support for XML. `.html()` doesn't support XML document. So, you'll need to either use the [traversing methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) and/or [XML DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_node.asp).

So, For example, you could do a depth-first traversal till you find a text node (i.e. [nodeType](http://www.w3schools.com/Dom/dom_nodetype.asp) == 3), and you can use `nodeName` (e.g. `<ul>`) and [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to get the tag name and the text.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method to preserve tags:

```
var legendStr = $(this).find('legendString').html();
```

Also note that `.find('legendString')` will look for a tag called `legendString` which probably is not what you are looking for. You probably need the [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector.

Comment: *Not working* is not a very precise problem description. Could you post a complete snippet that illustrates the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the function you need is in jQuery out-of-the-box. But you can write your own. Here is a starting point for you:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn, {
outerHtml: function(tagName) {
    var matches = this.find(tagName);
    var result = '';
    for (var i=0; i<matches.length; i++) {
        var el = matches[i];
        result += '<' + tagName;

        for (var i=0; i<el.attributes.length; i++) {
            result += ' ';
            result += el.attributes[i].name;
            result += "='";
            result += el.attributes[i].value;
            result += "'";
        }
        if (el.innerHTML == null) { result += '/>'; }
        else { 
        result += '>';
        result += el.innerHTML;
        result += '</'
        result += tagName;
        result += '>';
    }
    return result;
}
```

}});

thus, you'll be able to do

```
var legendString = $(this).outerHtml('legendString');
```